# Clear colspan in responsive table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a responsive table (set at 100% width within variable div width) in which I'm trying to 'reset' the colspan so that the next table row does not inherit the fixed width `td`s.

In my example the numbers td (1 to 7) have a fixed width of 40px which is given by the class 'position'. The next table row has two buttons, which should be 50% each. I can do this by adding the half class in the example, but this undoes the width of the 'position' class. As I have 8 tds I give the buttons each a colspan of 4, but the last button td inherits the width of the 4 'position' classes, so it's set at 160px fixed.. is it possible to clear the colspan and the fixed width of it?

The numbers could depend (1-7) so adding a colspan with equal number of the numbers would not be a good solution.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zt5W9/1/)

Comment: The code is working good. But the first `td` has biggest width than others. `colspan="4"` is selecting first 4 `td`s (name, 1, 2, 3) and the second `colspan` is selecting other 4 `td`s (4, 5, 6, 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment

"The code is working good. But the first `td` has biggest width than others. `colspan="4"` is selecting first 4 `td`s (name, 1, 2, 3) and the second `colspan` is selecting other 4 `td`s (4, 5, 6, 7)."

This can not work with `td`. Try this way if you want.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="8">
        <div class="half"><a href="#" class="button">Button one<a/></div>
        <div class="half"><a href="#" class="button">Button two<a/></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.half{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/zt5W9/2/

Comment: Hi Enve, thanks for confirming there is no other way. Might go for your solution, guess it's the best one. Thanks